# Javascript undefined error: ReferenceError: ALT is not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

What it is supposed to do - 
Example

```
url1(pages,"ALT") returns "www.xyz.ac.uk" 
url1(pages,"xyz") returns ""
```

The error - `ReferenceError: ALT is not defined`

This is just for some coursework, Im stuck with these errors. Any help would be much appreciated

```
function index(string,pattern,caseSensitive) {
    if(caseSensitive == false) {
        var v = string.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        var v = string;
    }

    return indexNumber = v.indexOf(pattern);
}
var pages = [ "|www.lboro.ac.uk|Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research.", "!www.xyz.ac.uk!An alternative University" , "%www%Yet another University"];

    alert(url1(pages, ALT));

function url1(pages,pattern) {
    var siteContent = [];
    for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
        var seperator = pages[i].charAt(0);
        if(pages[i].indexOf(seperator)>0){
            siteContent = pages[i].split(pages[i].indexOf(seperator));      
        }
        if( index(siteContent[2],pattern,false)>=0){
            return siteContent[1]; 
        }else{
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Java is similar to Javascript as Ham is similar to Hamster

Comment: Where is ALT set? It is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

So you call it like this:

```
alert(url1(pages, ALT));
```

Here alt is undefined because ALT is not a defined variable.

Call it with string?

```
url1(pages,"ALT");
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I now get this error TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: So where do you call 'toUpperCase' method? Maybe in index function? Add the code.

Comment: function index(string,pattern,caseSensitive) {
    if(caseSensitive == false) {
  var v = string.toUpperCase();
    } else {
     v = string;
    }

 return indexNumber = v.indexOf(pattern);
}

Comment: I don't know why you switch toUpperCase in index function because it just returns the index of the pattern. You should do that outside of this function.

Comment: Thank you Rok, however it does not work for these - Example
url1(pages,"ALT") returns "www.xyz.ac.uk" 
url1(pages,"xyz") returns ""

Comment: Sorry I just corrected some mistakes, it was late where I am :) Ok I modified it a bit more, tried to concentrate on what you were actually trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/27Jt8/3/

Comment: I guess that you wan't to search the pattern in a url not in the last string in the array? Also notice that I fill the results in the array, so this way the function will not end in the first iteration. Also you can have multiple matches that way. I hope that this is what you were looking for. If you have any more questions don't hesitate to ask.